# How to handle ISO-8859-1 encoded requests with the WSRequest API?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm currently trying to form a request to a really old website that doesn't use standard UTF-8 encoding and some of the query parameters have special characters such as *á*, *é* and *ã*.

I can't use URLEncoder prior to passing the query parameters because it'll reencode everything and make a mess out of the parameters.

So I need to either tell WSRequest to not encode anything, or to encode it in the way I want it to.

Here's my block that creates the request:

```
WSRequest request = ws.url(URL)
                .setQueryParameter("ST", uf)
                .setQueryParameter("CT", cap)
                .setQueryParameter("segment", segment)
                .setQueryParameter("period", period);
```

If I try to use the standard encoding on WSRequest, á will get encoded into %C3%A1 instead of %E1 which is what I actually want.

Comment: And.. what does this have to do with launching rich client GUIs from the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Had to switch to OkHttp for this one, since it supports adding query parameters that are already encoded through:

```
addEncodedQueryParameter(String key, String value)
```